# outlook 2010 freeze column header

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm generating HTML emails from Sql Server and some of the emails will contain a table with many, many rows. I'd like to implement frozen column headers, so that when scrolling the data (inside the email), the column header always remains visible. I've attempted many different solutions using css, to no avail. I understand Outlook won't recognize javascript - so I'm stuck with using css to do this - which I'm able to do in various web sites, but Outlook 2010 does not react the same way.

I understand the css engine in Outlook is really like going back to the days of 2001. Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to accomplish this. I'm only interested in Outlook functionality, as that is our only email vehicle.

I took a shot at using this code, which works in jsfiddle - but not in email:

```
<style type="text/css">
table, td {
text-align:center;
}

th {
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
}


table th {
padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
border-top:0;
border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
background: #ededed;
}

table th:first-child {
text-align: left;
}

table tr:first-child th:first-child {
border-top-left-radius:3px;
border-left: 0;
}

table tr:first-child th:last-child {
border-top-right-radius:3px;
}

table tr {
text-align: center;
}

table td:first-child {
text-align: left;
border-left: 0;
}

table td {
padding:10px;
border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
background: #fafafa;
}

table tr:last-child td {
border-bottom:0;
}

table tr:last-child td:first-child {
border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}

table tr:last-child td:last-child {
border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
}

table th, table td {
width: 160px;
}

#wrapper {
width: 740px;
height: 300px;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

table thead {
position:fixed;
}

</style>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<table>

<!-- Table Header -->
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Task Details</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Progress</th>
        <th>Vital Task</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<!-- Table Header -->



<!-- Table Body -->
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td>Create pretty table design</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>100%</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr><!-- Table Row -->

    <tr>
        <td>Take the dog for a walk</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>100%</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr><!-- Darker Table Row -->

    <tr>
        <td>Waste half the day on Twitter</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>20%</td>
        <td>No</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Feel inferior after viewing Dribble</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>80%</td>
        <td>No</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Wince at &quot;to do&quot; list</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>100%</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Vow to complete personal project</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>23%</td>
        <td>yes</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Procrastinate</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>80%</td>
        <td>No</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><a href="#yep-iit-doesnt-exist">Hyperlink Example</a></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>80%</td>
        <td><a href="#inexistent-id">Another</a></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
<!-- Table Body -->

</table>
</div>

</body>
```

Thanks so much for any help,
Paul

Comment: why not send a protected excel document?

Comment: I'm sending a link to excel files now, which has the frozen panes. Unfortunately, users don't seem to want to open the link. I need to have the content in the body of the email, so it's super easy for them.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Outlook doesn't support CSS position or overflow, so doing this in CSS looks as though it is not possible.

Because you are targeting Outlook only, you could try messing with [VML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb263872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That is mostly uncharted territory, so not sure if you can find something that works. Check out [backgrounds.cm](http://backgrounds.cm/) for an example of how VML can be applied to a html email. Let us know how it goes if you try that route.

Comment: Ok thank you John, I've played with VML before when I used to write classic asp code and then open the web site using excel. If I can make something work, I'll be sure to reply back.